# What is base.ItemAdded(properties);?

Tags: sharepoint

For event handling code the following code comes up as default:

```
base.ItemAdded(properties);
```

Can anybody tell me what it is used for?

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

This event handler notifies you of when an item has just been added to a sharepoint list so that you can do some post-processing on the item.  Use ItemAdding() if you want need to make changes to the item before it is posted to the list such as incrementing a unique record ID.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it calls it base Class's ItemAdded method which in turn calls another method BaseItemEventReceiver.
What this method does is set properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.Continue;
This just means that the event is allowed to continue (not cancelled).

As for me I always replace the line "base.ItemAdded(properties);" with my code and it works perfectly fine.